# MongoDB C# Driver - Conditional `UpdateDefinition`?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

What is the simpler way of doing this?

```c#
// var request = ...

var result = MyDbCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    a => otherConditions && a.MyObject != null,
    Builders<MyDocument>.Update
        .Set(a => a.MyObject!.A, request.A)
        .Set(a => a.MyObject!.B, request.B)
        .Set(a => a.MyObject!.C, request.C));

if (result.ModifiedCount <= 0)
{
    MyDbCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
        a => otherConditions && a.MyObject == null,
        Builders<MyDocument>.Update
            .Set(a => a.MyObject, new MyDocument.MyObject()
            {
                A = request.A,
                B = request.B,
                C = request.C
            }));
}
```

Notice the differing `a.MyObject != null` and `a.MyObject == null` conditions, ideally I want to do something like in this **pseudocode**:

```c#
MyDbCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    a => otherConditions
    Builders<MyDocument>.Update
        .Condition(a => a.MyObject != null)
        .Then(builder => builder
            .Set(a => a.MyObject!.A, request.A)
            .Set(a => a.MyObject!.B, request.B)
            .Set(a => a.MyObject!.C, request.C)
        )
        .Else(builder => builder
            .Set(a => a.MyObject, new MyDocument.MyObject()
            {
                A = request.A,
                B = request.B,
                C = request.C
            })
        )
```

I've wasted hours at this point trying to do it with **aggregation pipelines** where I keep getting this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException:
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'.
```

<strike>I don't have that code anymore so I can't copy paste it here. Sorry!</strike>

**EDIT 1**

My aggregation pipeline looked something like this combined with another `.Set` that set the properties inside of `MyObject`.

```
new PipelineUpdateDefinition<MyDocument>(
    new EmptyPipelineDefinition<MyDocument>().Match(a => a.MyObject == null)
).Set(a => a.MyObject, new MyDocument.MyObject());
```

**EDIT 2**

The use of `PipelineUpdateDefinition` (previous edit) kept giving me a `System.InvalidCastException`
(which is now a confirmed bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4745)

So I ***played*** around with something like this, but failed to introduce the `if NULL then SET ... else SET ...` logic.

> Note that `MyDocument` here is different from the previous `MyDocument` definitions.

```c#
await MyCollection.AggregateToCollectionAsync(
    EmptyPipelineDefinition<MyDocument>.Create(new[]
    {
        PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match<MyDocument>(
            a => a.A == A && a.B == B),
        Builders<MyDocument>.Update.Set(
                a => a.C,
                new[] { "hello" })
            .Render(
                BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<MyDocument>(),
                BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry)
            .ToBsonDocument(),
        PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Merge<MyDocument, MyDocument>(
            MyCollection,
            new MergeStageOptions<MyDocument>())
    }
));
```

Comment: Posted again at: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/conditional-updatedefinition/237838?u=hvfou

Comment: Try to use `ReplaceOneAsync` instead

Comment: @PauloGuimarães Unfortunately I can't do that because a NEW object would overwrite the other non (A/B/C) properties.

Comment: What is the version of this M.Drive? I did it in a different way.

Comment: For example `mongoCollection.UpdateOneAsync(ifilterDefinition, document, updateOptions);` so that you can filter in any way you want.

Comment: @PauloGuimarães I already use a filter as the first argument to `UpdateOneAsync`

Comment: The error you're seeing is quite simple, somewhere you have an array in the data, but you're trying to put this array into the document. You should provide full code and data example that triggers this error

Comment: @olfek, as I said, you also need to provide an example document that you're working with and structure of your clasees